# Call a Scala Embeded Method in External Java Action

Tags: scala, jface, emf, eclipse-sirius

I'm developing a program mixed with java and scala.
Eclipse : Eclipse Modeling Tool 2.4
Sirius : for model representation
Scala IDE

My situation is that I use External Java Action Interface in Sirius to extend modeling representation. Let say the class is A_Extend which is implement External Java Action Interface. A_Extend calls a JFace Class, B_GUI. The B_GUI calls Scala Function, C_Scala.
By the way, in the development mode ( it includes automatically generated model source code and A_Extend, and B_GUI and C_Scala codes), When I executed B_GUI as Java Application, it can call C_Scala (I set Scala nature). However, when I execute B_GUI using A_Extend in instance of Workbench (I clicked "run as Eclipse Application"), C_Scala is not called.
I thought it is because there is no Scala compiler in runtime Workbench, so I tried to include the Scala nature both on an instance model and odesign file. However, it does not work.

Are there any one who can help me?

Thank you so much in advance and have a wonderful day.

Best Regards,
Grace